Как оптимизированно использовать хуки в nextjs?
Как оптимизированно использовать хуки в nextjs?
Уже долгое время не могу понять использование хуков в next js. Чисто например есть компонент:
"use client"
import React from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

function Home() {
  const variable = useSelector((state) => state.app.something)
  return <div>
    <Something variable={variable}/>
  </div>;
}

export default Home;

Этот компонент рендерится на клиенте и его дочерние элементы будут тоже рендериться на клиенте как я понимаю. И тогда пропадает ssr для всей страницы (предположим что Home вышестоящий компонент). Что обычно делают чтобы оптимизировать все так чтобы содержимое могло рендериться на сервере?

Внутри клиентских компонентов вполне могут быть серверные.
